# How to create a SharePoint People Picker in .NET (MVC)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2013, peoplepicker

How to create something close to this in .NET MVC?:

[image: people picker image]

Basically people picker has these features:

- Search by name, email, user account
- Multi-select
  Users are in Active Directory (optionally also in a SharePoint site)

Answer (score 0):

SPServices might be of help, http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker.